# How to setup the environmental requirements for integration tests in golang?

Tags: go, integration-testing

I am new to golang and have two little projects started, where I got to the same problem.

One uses a MySQL database as a datastore and the other elasticsearch. How can I write tests which cover the code for that.

At first I’ve used a HashMapDatastore, but with that I can only test my handlers and business logic, but not the persistence layer (e.g. if the persisting and retrieving works as I expect in elasticsearch) (aka integration test).

So should I test if there is a blank database for testing?
How should I delete this db after each test? I’ve found an approach for this in the integration tests of docker/libcompose but it is relatively complex.

Is there a common approach for that? Testing if there is an elasticsearch with an empty index available and if not failing the tests with a good setupmessage?

Thanks

Comment: For SQL, i use this kind of tools : https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock , maybe this can help you

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't test if e.g. my database schema is valid and working. E.g. complicated SELECTS or testing the elasticsearch schema. The most advantages of go-sqlmock are that I don't have to write my MapDatastore on my own. That's very nice but doesn't help me with my integration problem, does it?

Comment: You're talking about integration tests. Docker is handy because you can `docker rm` it anytime to reset. I have been using Docker to test my Elasticsearch integration in my tests.

Comment: Just start a new docker on every test session with proper database import. If you have proper migration practice, you may check your schema on every test session. I'd use `Makefile` to store the docker setup code.

Comment: So you would suggest to put the docker setup and the `go test` into a Makefile and let the tests fail, if someone just runs the tests without starting the mysql docker? Or should I use a go docker library to start the docker container with the MySQL server in the test code? (Which leads to a simpler API, but what should I do if there is no docker available?)